# Adding new Viewcontroller's view as subview

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, swift3

I am trying with the following and failed to add new viewcontrollers view. Is it only way to present view controller ? Cant we add view from other storyboard viewcontrollers view?

```
  //Working
    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "customView") as! CustomViewController

    self.present( viewcontroller , animated: true, completion: nil)

    //Not working
    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "customView") as! CustomViewController
    vc.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(vc.view)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to also add `CustomViewController` as `ChildViewController` in your current Controller.

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "customView") as! CustomViewController
vc.view.frame = self.view.bounds
self.addChildViewController(vc)
self.view.addSubview(vc.view)
vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self) //OR  vc.willMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Comment: you missed the another one line

Comment: or use vc.willMove(toParentViewController: self)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Edited for that

Comment: thank you!  I have tried for adding some other views vc.customView to self.view but failed. Is this possible to add part of vc with defined frame into self.view like self.view.addsubview(vc.customview) : vc from storyboard

Comment: @GobiM I haven't try something like that, have you try by adding it, `vc.customview` is not load yet so may be it will give you nil, You can check it by simply trying once.

Comment: is this possible to add only the customview from vc without adding into childviewcontroller ? My requirement is to design custom view for viewcontorller into separate viewcontroller.

Comment: @GobiM Yes I got what you asking, I'm saying I haven't try this before so don't know about it, But may be it is doesn't look like possible.