# Set the ViewController on UIView programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, view, autolayout, viewcontroller

Is it possible to set the `viewController` for an `UIView` programmatically? What I want to do is make a `UIView` that always covers 50% of the screen's height and add a `ViewController` on that `view` after initializing it. I can't seem to find a method. Pseudocode:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.5)

//Can't seem to find a method that does exactly this:
view.setViewController(.......)
```

Comment: view.setViewController(.......) in this place use view.addsubview(yourVCname.view)

Comment: @OleAndré So you wanna have a view controller of which 50% are covered in a UIView, that is handled by a different view controller?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/a/42110439/6433023 for adding ViewController in view

Comment: @FlorensvonBuchwaldt Yes I have a master View Controller with UIViews inside it and I want different view controllers to lay out those views

Answer (score 0):

Insert `yourAnotherVC.view` as a subview to `yourview`

```
var MenuView: AnotherViewController? = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewsView") as? AnotherViewController)
    self.addChildViewController(MenuView)
    MenuView?.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    MenuView?.view?.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0.0), y: CGFloat(self.containerView.frame.size.height), width: CGFloat(self.containerView.frame.size.width), height: CGFloat(self.containerView.frame.size.height))
    yourview.insertSubview(MenuView?.view, belowSubview: self.bottomMenuView)

    //Show presentation logic here forward i mean show Anotherviewvc bottom to top or top to bottom
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll hide and show views instead of switching out the whole UIViews so no more answers needed #close

Answer (score 0):

```
// Add Child View Controller from your MainVC
    addChildViewController(viewController) //your 2nd VC

    // Add Child View as Subview
    view.addSubview(viewController.view)

    // Configure Child View
    viewController.view.frame = view.bounds //here you make it 50% of height!
    viewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    // Notify Child View Controller
    viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Container View, that uses its own UIViewController. Simply drag it from the object library and you are good to go.